# What does "user removed" mean, and what is its connection to a loss of reputation points?

Tags: support

I'm pretty sure I received today my first "user removed," which resulted in a loss of ten reputation points, but I am at a loss to know what it means.  Would someone please explain?  Thanks. Don

Answer (score 3):

It simply means that some user account was removed from the system and their votes went with them. This can happen when a user requests deletion or when a fraudulent duplicate account is detected.

It's nothing to worry about. Your reputation point loss wasn't even that much. I lost about 500 a while back on another site when an active high rep user decided to remove himself (and had apparently left me quite a few votes over time).

Comment: Is there a way to find out what votes got deleted with the user?  I just lost 30, and since there isn't a lot of traffic here, every point is hard to earn.

Comment: @BruceJames No there really isn't. Votes are anonymous in the system for a reason and those reasons don't just go away because a user decides to delete their account. If they want to go away that is their prerogative to do without their anonymity and past voting record being exposed. I wouldn't sweat it though. Sure every point is hard to earn, but don't worry too much about the points. Its a completely relative system anyway. Even the vote differential between 'popular' content and 'high quality content' caused by the net effect of crowd sourcing the system isn't something to sweat.